# How will we call a function written in a separate file from a Cypress test?

Tags: javascript, cypress

In Cypress.io test, I am calling a subtract function and tests written in the 'example-spec' as below. This is working fine. But how will we call the same subtract function written in a different js file, for example '/basetest.js' from the Cypress test?

```
describe ('Calling a function', function(){
it('Call the Subtract function and asert the calculation', function(){
    cy
    .wrap({sub: subValues})
    .invoke('sub', 15, 8)
    .should('eq', 7) // true        
    })

})
```

// Subtract function:

```
const subValues = (a, b) => {
  return a - b 
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html

Put this in your `support/commands.js` file:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('subValues', (a, b) => { return a - b });
```

Put this in your `support/index.js` file, if it isn't already there (it should be):

```
import "./commands";
```

Call it in your test like so:

```
describe ('Calling a function', function(){
  it('Call the Subtract function and asert the calculation', function(){
    cy
      .subValues(15, 8)
      .should('eq', 7) // true        
    });
});
```

Comment: +1, this answer is also true. I don't think you can do namespacing with this method, but it has the added advantage of being able to [operate on whatever cypress object it's called on](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Child-Commands), as in `cy.get("#elem").myCustomCommand()`.

Comment: Return statements aren't so friendly with cypress though. I get an error unless I wrap it and if I wrap it, it will return a chain that isn't the return.

Answer (score 18):

Add a new file to `cypress/support/`, e.g. `cypress/support/functions.js`

```js
cy.myproject = {
    makeUniqueUsername: () => {
        return 'cypress-test-' + Cypress.moment().format("YYMMDD-HHmmss");
    }
}
```

Include it by adding a reference to it in `cypress/support/index.js`

```js
import './functions'
```

Then call your function from any test

```js
describe('registration', function() {
    it('can register', function() {
        let username = cy.myproject.makeUniqueUsername();
        cy.visit('/register');
        cy.get('#username').type(username);
        // etc...
    })
});
```

---

When considering plain functions versus cypress "custom commands" note that the [cypress documentation encourage plain functions where custom commands aren't necessary in single spec files](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Best-Practices), though I don't agree with them that you shouldn't DRY test code.

---

*Thanks to the other answers for getting me to this*.
The main addition is making it step by step, and keeping custom functions out of the global `cy.*` namespace.

---

*Note:* By doing it this way as opposed to registering a command via `Cypress.Commands.add` you lose logging and time-travel in the Cypress UI. (Thanks @conny). It is up to you and your team which you value more for each case, the explicit steps or the IDE/linter/etc support from using plain js. Registering a command makes it an explicit step in the test rather than just a supporting function.

Comment: Given that this works I'm not actually clear what the advantage of registering a cypress command is. A downside of the registering a command is that it breaks IntelliJ's navigate-to-definition.

Comment: Registering your command via `Cypress.Commands.add` gives you logging and time-travel in the Cypress UI. This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for taking some time to explain this.

Answer (score 9):

Cypress includes an external library file, located by default at `(path to project)/support/index.js`.

This file is included in all test files, so you can put shared code here.

---

You can also include other files in the `support` folder with the following code in `index.js`:

```
import './MySupportFile.js'
```

---

When including an external test file, simple function definitions do not seem to carry over. I'm not exactly sure why. Inserting functions into the `cy` object has worked for me:

```
cy.myFunction = greeting => {
    console.log(greeting);
};

cy.myNamespace = {};

cy.myNamespace.myNamespacedFunction = () => {
    console.log("hi");
};
```

These functions in the `cy` object will carry over into any `/integration` files you have.

Comment: If you only want this function in one spec, you can `import` it into that spec directly instead of in the `support/index.js` file, which will import it to all specs

Comment: @Joshua I have added the function in index.js file and imported as below in top of test file ( in both ways ) .. 'import subValues from '../support/index' ;
import {subValues} from '../index' ;'   ...spec failed to run and throws error

Comment: It helps us know what the issue is if you provide the error you are seeing.  Also you don't need to `import` from the `support/index.js` file, cypress handles that automatically.  See https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html

Comment: @Brendan ..I am getting 'ReferenceError: subValues is not defined' while running the tests. I have added the function.. 'const subValues = (a, b) => {
  return a - b 
}' in the index.js file. How do the test file invoke this function ?

Comment: @soccerway Ah, I've had issues with this. I'll edit my answer, I completely forgot to mention it.

Comment: @soccerway I've finished editing my answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: The proper way to do this would be to follow the Custom Command syntax.  Put this in your `support/commands.js` file:  `Cypress.Commands.add('subValues', (a, b) => { return a - b.});`.  The call it from your test like this:  `cy.subValues(a, b);`.  Do not use an import statement.

Comment: @soccerway I moved my comment to a complete answer.  I put this into my cypress instance and have it passing.

Comment: @Brendan, Awesome, Now it is working fine, accepted your answer.