# Can Cypress Recognize Default Export Functions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, cypress, es6-modules

It seems that Cypress may not correctly recognize functions that are default exports.  Example:

```
export default function (array) {
  const randomValue = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
  return randomValue;
}
```

`import randomValueFromArray from '../../../../../support/index';`

```
randomValueFromArray([1, 2]).then((value) => {
    cy.log('VALUE', value);
  });
```

Cypress runner error:
`(0 , _index.default) is not a function`

Comment: Cannot reproduce, works correctly for me.  But `randomValueFromArray([1, 2]).then()` is not valid, since your function does not return a promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get it to work this way:

```
function randomValueFromArray(array) {
  const randomValue = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
  return randomValue;
}


module.exports = {
  randomValueFromArray,
};
```

Then import and call it using:

```
import { randomValueFromArray } from '../../../../../support/index';

let warehouse;

  warehouse = randomValueFromArray([1, 2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In cypress you can add this function as custom commands in `support/commands.js` file:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("randomValueFromArray", (array) => { return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)]; })
```

& Use it the spec make sure to add `import './commands'` in `support/index.js`

```
   cy.randomValueFromArray([1,2,5,6,3,8,9,2,5,7]).then((value) => {
        cy.log('VALUE', value);
      })
```

Comment: We had it as a command, but now need to also use it in a file that runs outside of the browser, so `cy` commands aren't available.

Comment: @anutter Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60714505/5324105 . It may help .